# Crystal Reports GetAttributes

Tags: crystal-reports

I've been asked to go through over 1000 Crystal Reports to find the Store Procedures and/or Table names used in each report. I would like to do this programmatically, but I don't see much in the way of reading such values from the CR object model.

There is a **GetAttributes** method on the ReportDocument object, but I don't know if that's the right place to look.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetAttributes wasn't what I needed. This is what I used instead (using a list of files from a directory...)

```
 foreach (string repFile in filePaths)
            {
                string reportName = repFile.ToString().Replace(folderPath, "");
                string tableName = string.Empty; 
                string cmdText = string.Empty; 
                string storedProc = string.Empty;

                try 
                {           
                    cryRpt.Load(repFile);
                }
                catch (Exception rptErr)
                {
                    lblResults.Text += reportName + " - generated Error: " + rptErr.Message + Environment.NewLine; ;
                }

                cmdText = cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula.ToString();

                foreach (Table tab in cryRpt.Database.Tables)
                {
                    if (tab.Name.ToUpper().Contains("RPT_") || tab.Name.ToUpper().Contains("SP_"))
                    {
                        storedProc = tab.Name;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tableName = tab.Name;
                    }
                }
```